# Two sentences from Boston Legal that confuse me

Tags: meaning, passive-voice

> You've had five marriages dissolve

Grammatically, should this sentence be "You've had five marriages dissolved?" Just like the structure "I got my hair done"

> Well, here's a flash for you. We're all desperate to be relevant.

In this sentence, what's the meaning of "to be relevant"?

Answer (score 1):

Recognize that this is not the perfect tense *had dissolved*.  This is the perfect tense of *have* (have had) implying *ownership* or *experience*

> She's had her life **take** some unexpected turns lately.

This structure is also akin to the passive tense.  By making *the marriage* the subject, it implies no fault -- no one actively *dissolved* the marriage or *had* someone else do it.  It just happened on its own.  Another example:

> You've had your house **increase** in value lately, haven't you?

implies the increase is something that happened "on its own".  Compare this with

> You've had your house **repainted** lately, haven't you?

which implies that I took action to have someone else repaint the house.

*To be relevant* is, I think, a somewhat modern idiomatic expression that means to be of *importance* or of *significance* to some group.

> As our children become adults we have to acknowledge that we inevitably **are** less **relevant** to their lives.

Answer (score 0):

> You've had five marriages dissolve

Having a marriage **dissolved** implies a judge has ruled it ended and/or annulled.

Having a marriage **dissolve** implies a judge may have ruled it over, or maybe it is only *effectively* over. Maybe it dissolved on its own... there is no hope of it recovering... but the divorce is not legally final.

So maybe... he had four marriages dissolved and the current one is in process.

Answer (score 0):

> You've had five marriages dissolve

From Carl

> Having a marriage dissolved implies a judge has ruled it ended and/or
>   annulled.

I believe it is using dissolve as a metaphor, for coming apart, disapearing.

so it is the same as the sentence "you have had five sugar cubes dissolve"

Answer (score -1):

> You've had five marriages **dissolve**

Is correct, the analogous example would be

> I had my hair **cut**.

not

> I had my hair **cutted**.

For your second part,

> to be relevent

means "***to matter***", "***to be important***" and have "***social stature***" where people will ask you for or listen to your opinion.

Comment: "cut" can be a noun. Is "dissolve" a noun here?

Comment: @马化腾  *Cut* is not a noun in Peter's example.  *Dissolve* is not a noun.